# Self Web Hosting with cpanel - What are detailed software as well as hardware requirements do I need to meet?

Tags: cpanel, web-hosting

I recently deployed my website in the live shared resource server in Linux environment. The website is a Property Listing Application that allows real estate agents to list their properties with 18 High Definition (HD) images per listing.

My Web Hosting Provider configured the php.ini file for upload_max_filesize at 20MB. I tried different possible configurations to increase the upload size whether through php scripting in cpnel or progammatically but I got connection time out without notification error.
I spoke to Techical Support Team who increased the upload_max_filesize to 50MB that allowed me to only upload 16 images of 3MB size each. But when I tried, the image upload failed still.

I noticed that the cpanel  master settings override all the changes. I wanted to upgrade the package for VPS but its features don't convice my ideal server settings.

I decided to concider a self web hosting with control panel. I investigated some possibilities and did some research online to find out how I can accomplish this, I found a few tips that showed possibilities with drawbacks.

I would like to know if it is possible for the self web hosting. What will be server requirements like number of CPUs, Raid, RAM and HDD sizes, etc. What is the most trusted server manufacturers like Cisco, Dell, etc. For Software between Windows and Linux. What is the best fit and why? What is a good cpanel to consider?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my upload issues. The problem was not upload_max_filsize but the actual image resolution in my script that needed a slight modication. I just modified the image resolution and the upload file image work fine.

For the ideal cpanel, I found cpanel.net